# How to upload images to AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm trying to upload images to Aws Amplify. First of all I'm not even sure if that's how it is done since I'm fairly new to AWS but I have a model in which there's an array of string that holds images links addresses that I use for display in the app. Now I'm trying to do the opposite by uploading images from the react native app to AWS amplify knowing a link needs to be created after uploading. How would I proceed to doing that is what I need to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amplify Storage actually utilizes S3, so you'd be creating an S3 storage bucket and uploading your images to that. The Amplify libraries provide an easy way to do all of this.

- An overview of the upload process: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/browser-based-uploads-aws-amplify.html
- Amplify JS documentation for the put method: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/